# Unable to run Selenium WebDriver tests with Internet Explorer Driver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I encountered an error like below in the console tab during run my selenium tests using Java.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$1(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.build(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:230)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:251)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:146)
    at superadminmodule.LoginInPage.main(LoginInPage.java:11)
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup **InternetExplorerDriver** on your pc.Download from this [place](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) and unzip IEDriverServer.zip as you like.Place is in your pc [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).See more detail from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

If you use selenium web driver with JUnit or some other testing framework, you need to setup InternetExplorerDriver path into your code.See my JUnit sample setup;

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

This [blog](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.sg/2014/02/how-to-create-and-run-junit-test-suit.html) has some selenium junit tutorials.You can also search many tutorials using google.com :D

Comment: You can download IEDriverServer.exe from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/  based on your OS (32 or 64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set path for the IE driver. Before that you need to download IE Driver from SeleniumHQ website. you can download it from below link **[Seleniumhq download](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","path/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property before hand.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Eclipse  Workspace\\MultiBrowser\\IEDriverServer.exe");

WebDriver obj = new InternetExplorerDriver();

obj.get("http://www.google.com/");

obj.close();
```